# Fatal error: Call to a member function addToChildGroup() app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php on line 759

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have added this code for block in catalog.xml and i got following error -

Fatal error: Call to a member function addToChildGroup() app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php on line 759

`<!-- custom change  here-->`

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" as="product_additional_data" after="product.info.upsell" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>

<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>                    

                <action method="setItemLimit"><type>related</type><limit>4</limit></action>
</block>
<!-- custom change  here-->
```

Comment: There is not a chance we could reasonably answer this without seeing what is around the line 759 of `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php`

Answer (score 7):

You closed your block here:

```
<block ... />
```

I suppose that causes the error.

Try this code:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" as="product_additional_data" after="product.info.upsell" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml">
  <action method="setColumnCount">
    <columns>4</columns>
  </action>                    
  <action method="setItemLimit">
    <type>related</type>
    <limit>4</limit>
  </action>
</block>
```

Comment: Thanks dude.. I faced the same issue and I make a mistake in my catalog.xml. So only I got the abpve problem. Now it solved.. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I got similar kind of  problem when I worked on github repository.I installed an extension on the local system then pushed the code to GitHub. 
Next  day when I removed extension from github and moved the code to development server.Then I faced same kind of problem.

For me clearing the caches worked